# Unity Error CS0120

Tags: unity-game-engine

I just got into unity3d, and i was using a guide. But every time I try to compile, I get Error CS0120. Please just help me instead of marking it as duplicate.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

void FixedUpdate () {
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal,0.0f,moveVertical);
    Rigidbody.AddForce(movement*speed*Time.deltaTime);


}
```

}

Answer (score 4):

This line is the issue

```
Rigidbody.AddForce(movement*speed*Time.deltaTime);
```

The error you are getting is that

> error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `UnityEngine.Rigidbody.AddForce(UnityEngine.Vector3)'

If you wanted to AddForce to a rigidbody attatched to the same gameobject as your script, then you need to grab that ridigbody instance and apply force, like this.

```
this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(movement*speed*Time.deltaTime);
```